# Qual a origem do termo "moleque"?

Tags: etimologia, português-brasileiro, origem-histórica, substantivos

Essa palavra já foi (e ainda é) motivo pra muita discussão e controvérsia, principalmente pelo fato de ser altamente desencorajado por alguns o uso dessa palavra, uns por ser a versão aportuguesada de Moloch (também escrito como Moloque ou Moleque, a divindade amonita para qual eram feitos sacrifícios infantis), outros por no estado do Ceará significar "demônio; satanás", outros citam até mesmo o idioma Iorubá, dizendo que significa "espírito zombeteiro", enquanto outros dizem que na verdade vem do quimbundo significando "filho pequeno".

Mas afinal, qual é a verdadeira origem e significado etimológico de "moleque"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Todos os dicionários que consultei — Houaiss, Academia das Ciências de Lisboa, [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/moleque), etc. — concordam que  ***moleque*** vem do quimbundo *muleke*, que significa ‘garoto, filho pequeno’. E os primeiros exemplos que encontramos do uso da palavra são coerentes com esta tese. O Houaiss indica que a palavra já estava em uso em 1716. A exemplo mais antigo que encontrei no Google Books é de [1727 nas *Memórias Historicas* de Fr. Manoel de Sá](https://books.google.pt/books?id=naddAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA411&dq=moleque&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2_Ij6t6nNAhUrLMAKHUKWBfQQ6AEIIDAA#v=onepage&q=moleque&f=false) (grafia original e ênfase minha em todas as citações):

> O segundo foy , que estando em Itapicurú, e sendo já notória a sua virtude, lhe rogou hum dos moradores da dita terra, quisesse ir ver hum ***moleque***, que tinha em artigos de morte, por ter atravessada na garganta huma espinha de peixe denominado Buge.

O exemplo seguinte é já de 1816, numa espécie de carta publicada em [*Macarronea Latino-Portugueza*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ksEDAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA287-IA7&dq=moleque&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk3oy1vKnNAhWKI8AKHYF2C2wQ6AEIJTAB#v=onepage&q=moleque&f=false), em que o autor respeitosamente se subscreve:

> Sou, e serei de v. m.
>   Criado seis furos abaixo de moleque

Encontramos também *moleque* no Dicionário Morais Silva de 1831:

> MOLÉQUE, s. m. pretinho, negro pequeno.

E também neste [*Novo Dicionario Francez-Português* de 1836:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=F4QTAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA657&dq=moleque&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk3oy1vKnNAhWKI8AKHYF2C2wQ6AEIUDAH#v=onepage&q=moleque&f=false)

> NÉGRILLON, NE, *s. fam. Dim*. (negrilhôn, ne) negrinho, moleque, pretinho, a.

Parece-me portanto que não têm razão de ser as controvérsias em torno da origem da palavra.

Comment: @BrunoLopes Reformulei a conclusão para eliminar quaisquer ambiguidades :)